# ListView populated from DB not showing?

Tags: java, android, sqlite, android-layout

Records added to DB by calling DBAdapter insert method on another activity
No runtime errors, data seems to be added to db properly, however the listview object does not appear when app is being run

Main Activity

```
public class MainScreen extends ActionBarActivity implements View.OnClickListener
{

 Button addNewButton;
 Button sortByNameButton;
 Button sortByBusinessButton;
 Button sortByPhoneButton;
 DBAdapter userDB;
 ListView cardList;



@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(layout.activity_main_screen);
    //declare buttons
    addNewButton= (Button)findViewById(R.id.addNewButton);
    sortByNameButton= (Button)findViewById(R.id.sortByNameButton);
    sortByBusinessButton= (Button)findViewById(R.id.sortByBusinessButton);
    sortByPhoneButton= (Button)findViewById(R.id.sortByPhoneButton);
    //set onclick listeners
    addNewButton.setOnClickListener(this);
    //set button to font
    addNewButton.setText("Add New");
    sortByNameButton.setText("Sort by Name");
    sortByBusinessButton.setText("Sort by Business");
    sortByPhoneButton.setText("Sort by Phone #");
    userDB = new DBAdapter(this);
    userDB.open();
    cardList=(ListView) findViewById(id.cardList);
    populateListViewFromDB();


}
 @Override
 public void onDestroy(){
     userDB.close();
 }
 private void populateListViewFromDB() {
    Cursor cursor = userDB.getAllRows();
    //allow activity to manage cursor lifetime (dont want memory leak)
    startManagingCursor(cursor);
    //map from cursor to view fields
    String[] fromFieldNames = new String[]{DBAdapter.KEY_BUS_NAME};

    int[] toViewIDs = new int[]{R.id.business_name};

    //adapter to map out columns and rows of DB (deprecated, but it's okay)
    SimpleCursorAdapter cursorAdapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(
            this, //context
            R.layout.item_layout, //layout template
            cursor, //cursor
            fromFieldNames, //information
            toViewIDs //where to put information
    );
    //String[] vals = {"me","you","he","she"};
    //ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, layout.activity_main_screen, vals);
    //set adapter to list view element

    cardList.setAdapter(cursorAdapter);
   }
}
```

DBAdapter class:

```
public class DBAdapter {


private static final String TAG = "DBAdapter";

// DB Fields
public static final String KEY_ROWID = "_id";
public static final int COL_ROWID = 0;
/*
 * CHANGE 1:
 */
// TODO: Setup your fields here:
public static final String KEY_BUS_NAME = "BusinessName";
public static final String KEY_PERS_NAME = "PersonalName";
public static final String KEY_ADDRESS = "Address";
public static final String KEY_PHONE_NUM = "PhoneNum";
public static final String KEY_EMAIL = "Email";

// TODO: Setup your field numbers here (0 = KEY_ROWID, 1=...)
public static final int COL_BUS_NAME = 1;
public static final int COL_PERS_NAME = 2;
public static final int COL_ADDRESS = 3;
public static final int COL_PHONE_NUM = 4;
public static final int COL_EMAIL = 5;


public static final String[] ALL_KEYS = new String[] {KEY_ROWID, KEY_BUS_NAME, KEY_PERS_NAME, KEY_ADDRESS, KEY_PHONE_NUM, KEY_EMAIL};

// DB info: its name, and the table we are using (just one).
public static final String DATABASE_NAME = "LocalCards";
public static final String DATABASE_TABLE = "CardInfo";
// Track DB version if a new version of your app changes the format.
public static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 3;

private static final String DATABASE_CREATE_SQL =
        "create table " + DATABASE_TABLE
                + " (" + KEY_ROWID + " integer primary key autoincrement, "
        /*
         * CHANGE 2:
         */
                // TODO: Place your fields here!
                // + KEY_{...} + " {type} not null"
                //  - Key is the column name you created above.
                //  - {type} is one of: text, integer, real, blob
                //      (http://www.sqlite.org/datatype3.html)
                //  - "not null" means it is a required field (must be given a value).
                // NOTE: All must be comma separated (end of line!) Last one must have NO comma!!
                + KEY_BUS_NAME + " text, "
                + KEY_PERS_NAME + " text, "
                + KEY_ADDRESS + " text, "
                + KEY_PHONE_NUM + " text, "
                + KEY_EMAIL + " text"

                // Rest  of creation:
                + ");";

// Context of application who uses us.
private final Context context;

private DatabaseHelper myDBHelper;
private SQLiteDatabase db;

/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
//  Public methods:
/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

public DBAdapter(Context ctx) {
    this.context = ctx;
    myDBHelper = new DatabaseHelper(context);
    //Cursor x = db.rawQuery("SELECT "+KEY_BUS_NAME+" FROM " + DATABASE_TABLE,null);
}

// Open the database connection.
public DBAdapter open() {
    db = myDBHelper.getWritableDatabase();
    //db.execSQL(DATABASE_CREATE_SQL);
    return this;
}

// Close the database connection.
public void close() {
    myDBHelper.close();
}

// Add a new set of values to the database.
public void insertRow(String bus_name, String pers_name, String address, String phone, String email) {
    /*
     * CHANGE 3:

    // TODO: Update data in the row with new fields.
    // TODO: Also change the function's arguments to be what you need!
    // Create row's data:
    ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
    values.put(KEY_BUS_NAME, bus_name);
    values.put(KEY_PERS_NAME, pers_name);
    values.put(KEY_ADDRESS, address);
    values.put(KEY_PHONE_NUM, phone);
    values.put(KEY_EMAIL, email);*/

    // Insert it into the database.
    //return db.insert(DATABASE_TABLE, null, values);

    db.rawQuery("INSERT INTO " + DATABASE_TABLE + " (" + KEY_BUS_NAME + "," + KEY_PERS_NAME + "," +
            KEY_ADDRESS + "," + KEY_PHONE_NUM + "," + KEY_EMAIL + ") VALUES (" + "'" + bus_name +
            "','" + pers_name + "','" + address + "','" + phone + "','" + email + "');",null);
}

// Delete a row from the database, by rowId (primary key)
public boolean deleteRow(long rowId) {
    String where = KEY_ROWID + "=" + rowId;
    return db.delete(DATABASE_TABLE, where, null) != 0;
}

public void deleteAll() {
    Cursor c = getAllRows();
    long rowId = c.getColumnIndexOrThrow(KEY_ROWID);
    if (c.moveToFirst()) {
        do {
            deleteRow(c.getLong((int) rowId));
        } while (c.moveToNext());
    }
    c.close();
}

// Return all data in the database.
public Cursor getAllRows() {
    String where = null;
    Cursor c =  db.query(true, DATABASE_TABLE, ALL_KEYS,
            where, null, null, null, null, null);
    //Cursor c = db.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM " + DATABASE_TABLE, null);
    if (c != null) {
        c.moveToFirst();
    }
    return c;
}

// Get a specific row (by rowId)
public Cursor getRow(long rowId) {
    String where = KEY_ROWID + "=" + rowId;
    Cursor c =  db.query(true, DATABASE_TABLE, ALL_KEYS,
            where, null, null, null, null, null);
    if (c != null) {
        c.moveToFirst();
    }
    return c;
}

// Change an existing row to be equal to new data.
public boolean updateRow(long rowId, String bus_name, String pers_name, String address, String phone, String email) {
    String where = KEY_ROWID + "=" + rowId;

    /*
     * CHANGE 4:
     */
    // TODO: Update data in the row with new fields.
    // TODO: Also change the function's arguments to be what you need!
    // Create row's data:
    ContentValues newValues = new ContentValues();
    newValues.put(KEY_BUS_NAME, bus_name);
    newValues.put(KEY_PERS_NAME, pers_name);
    newValues.put(KEY_ADDRESS, address);
    newValues.put(KEY_PHONE_NUM, phone);
    newValues.put(KEY_EMAIL, email);

    // Insert it into the database.
    return db.update(DATABASE_TABLE, newValues, where, null) != 0;
}



/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
//  Private Helper Classes:
/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

/**
 * Private class which handles database creation and upgrading.
 * Used to handle low-level database access.
 */
private static class DatabaseHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper
{
    DatabaseHelper(Context context) {
        super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase _db) {
        _db.execSQL(DATABASE_CREATE_SQL);
    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase _db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
        Log.w(TAG, "Upgrading application's database from version " + oldVersion
                + " to " + newVersion + ", which will destroy all old data!");

        // Destroy old database:
        _db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + DATABASE_TABLE);

        // Recreate new database:
        onCreate(_db);
    }
}
}
```

item_layout.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
    android:text="Large Text"
    android:id="@+id/business_name"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
    android:text="Medium Text"
    android:id="@+id/personal_name"
    android:layout_below="@+id/business_name"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true" />

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
    android:text="Small Text"
    android:id="@+id/phone_number"
    android:layout_below="@+id/business_name"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true" />

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
    android:text="Small Text"
    android:id="@+id/email"
    android:layout_below="@+id/phone_number"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true" />
```

activity_main_screen.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<Button
    android:layout_width="75dp"
    android:layout_height="50dp"
    android:text="Sort by Name"
    android:id="@+id/sortByNameButton"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true" />

<Button
    android:layout_width="100dp"
    android:layout_height="50dp"
    android:text="Sort by Business"
    android:id="@+id/sortByBusinessButton"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/sortByNameButton" />

<Button
    android:layout_width="100dp"
    android:layout_height="50dp"
    android:text="Sort by Phone"
    android:id="@+id/sortByPhoneButton"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/sortByBusinessButton" />

<Button
    android:layout_width="75dp"
    android:layout_height="50dp"
    android:text="Add New"
    android:id="@+id/addNewButton"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/sortByPhoneButton"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/sortByPhoneButton" />

<SearchView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/searchBox"
    android:layout_below="@+id/sortByNameButton"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignRight="@+id/addNewButton"

/>

<ListView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/cardList"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_below="@+id/searchBox" />

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="New Text"
    android:id="@+id/textView"
    android:layout_below="@+id/searchBox"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/cardList"
    android:layout_alignRight="@+id/searchBox"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true" />
```

Comment: put your xml file/code that is related to listview..

Comment: Your xml file is ok. debug your code to ensure that you have data in your database. And then try another way to populate listview..... You can populate your listview without any adapter (If you want)....